# Why varying blob size gives different performance?

Tags: cassandra, scalability, cql

My cassandra table looks like this -

```
CREATE TABLE cs_readwrite.cs_rw_test (
    part_id bigint,
    s_id bigint,
    begin_ts bigint,
    end_ts bigint,
    blob_data blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (part_id, s_id, begin_ts, end_ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (s_id ASC, begin_ts DESC, end_ts DESC)
```

When I insert 1 million row per client, with 8 kb blob per row and test the speed of insertions from different client hosts the speed is almost constant at ~100 mbps. But with the same table definition, from same client hosts if I insert rows with 16 bytes of blob data then my speed numbers are dramatically low ~4 to 5 mbps. Why is there such a speed difference? I am only measuring write speeds for now. My main concern is not speed (though some inputs will help) when I add more clients I see speed is almost constant for bigger blob size but for 16 bytes blob the speed is increasing only by 10-20% per added client before it becomes constant.

I have also looked at bin/nodetool tablehistograms output and do adjust number of partitions in my test data so no partition is > 100 mb.

Any insights/ links for documentation would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: how are you measuring the throuhgput in Mbps?

Comment: I use chrono library to get start and end times and then measure total time taken in seconds, the data size is fixed if it is 8kb blob then 8kb * 1 million rows. Convert data in Mbs/ time in seconds. For multiple simultaneous hosts => total data/ max time in seconds.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, with the 16bytes payload, you again checked how much time it took to add 1 million rows and then applied the same formula?

Comment: yes. 1 million rows from each host. I increase number of hosts which are sending the data to same Cassandra cluster simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are measuring the throughput in the wrong way. The throughput should be measured in *transactions per second* and not in *data written per second*.

Even though the amount of data written can play a role in determining the write throughput of a system but usually it depends on many other factors.

- Compaction Strategy like STCS is write-optimized whereas LOCS is
  read-optimized.
- Connection speed and latency between the client and the cluster, and 
  between machines in the cluster
- CPU usage of the node which is processing data, sending data to other
  replicas and waiting for their acknowledgment.

Most of the writes are immediately written in memory instead of being written directly in the disk which basically makes the impact of the amount of data being written on final write throughput almost negligible whereas other *fixed* things like Network delay, CPU to coordinate the processing of data across nodes, etc have a bigger impact.

The way you should see it is that with 8KB of payload you are getting X transactions per second and with 16 Bytes you are getting Y transactions per second. Y will always be better than X but it will not be linearly proportional to the size difference.

You can find how writes are handled in cassandra explained in detail [here](https://blog.softwaremill.com/cassandra-writes-in-depth-6ea8d7581eb?gi=7eaa8c9e04b6).

Comment: what you're talking about is performance from Cassandra cluster. I am interested in client speed. I understand that Cassandra is perhaps doing the same amount of writes but why is client speed decreasing is not clear.

Comment: Isn't client speed a function of your server. If your server is slow, client will also take more time to complete request.

Answer (score 1):

Theres management overhead in Cassandra per row/partition, the more data (in bytes) you have in each row the less that overhead impacts throughput in bytes/sec. The reverse is true if you look at rows per sec as a metric of throughput. The larger the payloads the worse your rows/sec throughput would get.

Comment: didn't know about management overhead per row thanks for mentioning it.